# mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysqli

No puedo encontrar el error en mi código, este error esta en el `mysqli_fetch_row`. a continuación mi código

```
<?php

$db_host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="proyectoicel";

$db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
 if (!$db_connection){
    echo'No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos';}

$selectvistaprevia = "SELECT informe.codigoinforme, 
    informe.fechainforme, 
    equipo.nombreEquipo, 
    equipo.codigomaximo, 
    equipo.codigoactivofijoinventario, 
    equipo.codigocentrocosto, 
    cliente.nombrecliente, 
    marca.nombremarca, 
    modelo.descripcionmodelo, 
    serie.codigoserie, 
    tipomovimiento.descripcionmovimiento, 
    tipotrabajo.descripciontipotrabajo, 
    tipoestadoequipo.descripciontipoestadoequipo, 
    count(puntomantencion.descripcionprotocolo),
    count(instrumentomedicion.nombreinstrumentomedicion), 
    count(puntomantencionequipo.chequepuntomantencionequipo), 
    observacionmantencion.descripcionobservacionmantencion, 
    condicionfinalequipo.descripcionestadofinalequipo 
    FROM informe 
    INNER JOIN clienteequipo ON clienteequipo.codigoinforme = informe.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN cliente ON clienteequipo.codigocliente = cliente.codigocliente 
    INNER JOIN equipo ON clienteequipo.codigoequipo = equipo.codigoequipo 
    INNER JOIN marcamodelo ON marcamodelo.codigoinforme = informe.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN marca ON marca.codigomarca = marcamodelo.codigomarca 
    INNER JOIN modelo ON modelo.codigomodelo = marcamodelo.codigomodelo 
    INNER JOIN serie ON equipo.codigoequipo = serie.codigoequipo 
    INNER JOIN tipomovimientoequipo ON tipomovimientoequipo.codigoinforme = informe.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN tipomovimiento ON tipomovimiento.codigotipomovimiento = tipomovimientoequipo.codigotipomovimiento 
    INNER JOIN tipotrabajoequipo ON informe.codigoinforme = tipotrabajoequipo.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN tipotrabajo ON tipotrabajo.codigotipotrabajo = tipotrabajoequipo.codigotipotrabajo 
    INNER JOIN tipoestadoequipodelequipo ON informe.codigoinforme = tipoestadoequipodelequipo.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN tipoestadoequipo ON tipoestadoequipo.codigotipoestadoequipo = tipoestadoequipodelequipo.codigotipoestadoequipo 
    INNER JOIN instrumentoequipo ON informe.codigoinforme = instrumentoequipo.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN instrumentomedicion ON instrumentoequipo.codigoinstrumentomedicion = instrumentomedicion.codigoinstrumentomedicion 
    INNER JOIN puntomantencionequipo ON informe.codigoinforme = puntomantencionequipo.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN puntomantencion ON puntomantencion.codigoprotocolo = puntomantencionequipo.codigoprotocolo 
    INNER JOIN observacionmantencion ON informe.codigoinforme = observacionmantencion.codigoinforme 
    INNER JOIN condicionfinalequipo ON condicionfinalequipo.codigoestadofinalequipo = observacionmantencion.codigoestadofinalequipo 
    WHERE informe.codigoinforme = 997 
    and informe.estadoinforme = 1 
    GROUP BY informe.codigoinforme, 
        equipo.codigoequipo,
        cliente.codigocliente, 
        marca.codigomarca, 
        modelo.codigomodelo,
        serie.codigoserie, 
        tipomovimiento.descripcionmovimiento, 
        tipotrabajo.descripciontipotrabajo, 
        tipoestadoequipo.descripciontipoestadoequipo,
         observacionmantencion.descripcionobservacionmantencion,
        condicionfinalequipo.descripcionestadofinalequipo 
    limit 1";


$mostrar = mysqli_query($db_connection, $selectvistaprevia);


echo '

<div class="">
<table class="table table-bordered bg-info"> 

<tr>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>
<TH>Numero Informe</TH>
<TH>Fecha</TH>


<TH>Restaurar</TH>
</tr> ';

while ($rowi = mysqli_fetch_row($mostrar)){ 
echo '
    <tr>
    <td>'.$rowi['informe.codigoinforme'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['informe.fechainforme'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['equipo.nombreEquipo'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['equipo.nombreEquipo'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['equipo.codigomaximo'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['equipo.codigoactivofijoinventario'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['equipo.codigocentrocosto'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['cliente.nombrecliente'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['marca.nombremarca'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['modelo.descripcionmodelo'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['serie.codigoserie'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['tipomovimiento.descripcionmovimiento'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['tipotrabajo.descripciontipotrabajo'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['tipoestadoequipo.descripciontipoestadoequipo'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['instrumentomedicion.nombreinstrumentomedicion'].'</td><td>'.$rowi['observacionmantencion.descripcionobservacionmantencion'].'</td>
    <td>'.$rowi['condicionfinalequipo.descripcionestadofinalequipo'].'</td>

            <td>
     <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" onclick=ActualizarRestaurarCliente('.$rowi['informe.codigoinforme'].')><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Restaurar</button></td>
    </tr>

</script>';}

echo '</table>
</div>
    ';


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso sucede porque la consulta que estás haciendo tiene un error.
[`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) devuelve `FALSE` si la consulta da error.

Prueba ejecutando esa consulta en [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) o alguna otra herramienta para ver qué está fallando.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las alternativas, sería agregar lo siguiente:

`if (is_object($mostrar)) {
 // Código donde se procesa el arreglo. (ciclo 'while')
}`

Esto evitaría que se provocaran errores al intentar procesar una variable que no terminó como se esperaba (objeto).